# Wifi drivers on Acer swift

Tags: linux, drivers, kali-linux

I want to make my Laptop a dual OS Computer. Windows installed, everything works fine. When I try to install Kali Linux over my Install USB Stick, it says there are drivers missing. It says I can insert a USB Stick with drivers and install them, but I can't seem to find them. My Laptop doesn't have an Ethernet connection, so I can't follow the usual guides for this Problem. Can you help?

Comment: Install Kali as a VM with a VM App that support USB pass through. Vastly easier and will let you learn Kali. Posted from my Kali 2022.3 virtual machine.

Comment: Look for the Linux driver specific to the WiFi adapter on *your* machine. Check the specs for the adapter make and model, and search online.